# spring-cloud refresh an individual bean by name

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Quote from [spring-cloud-doc](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR5/single/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope):

> The RefreshScope is a bean in the context and it has a public method refreshAll() to refresh all beans in the scope by clearing the target cache. There is also a refresh(String) method to refresh an individual bean by name. This functionality is exposed in the /refresh endpoint (over HTTP or JMX).

How could I invoke the `/refresh` endpoint to refresh an individual bean (`@RefreshScope`) by name? The source code of spring-cloud-commons didn't tell me that. Or I understand "this functionality" wrong.

Comment: so far refreshing a single bean is only available via jmx

Comment: I clarified the documentation https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/commit/13237ee38b75455226f63980ee9e0a1efd043fba